# How to apply reversed filter when the mouse leaves an element in css?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<style>

    .huerotate:hover {
        -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(235deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    }
</style>

    <img class="huerotate" src="/images/header.png" alt="My Image">
```

The `:hover` selector will apply to the element while the mouse is over it, what CSS attribute should I use for mouse out to apply the filter in reverse?

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FMghK/83/)

Answer (score 2):

without :hover you have the "reverse" that you are looking for:

```
.huerotate{
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.huerotate:hover {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(235deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

The first is the normal state, when you hover enter in pseudo :hover and when mouse leave enter the normal state

Comment: Normal state should already be `hue-rotate(0deg)` and so I think the `filter` is not required originally :)

Comment: No, isn't required, but the transition is required. I write all only to show how to use it. Thank you for the appointment.

Comment: Yep, the transition is required because otherwise it will abruptly go back to original state.

Answer (score 1):

I maked a fiddle example, is this what you want ?
http://jsfiddle.net/14f7yorh/

```
.huerotate:hover {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(235deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
}
.huerotate {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
}
```